# Stoneham number expansion

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

How can we calculate  the  expansion of the a Stoneham number $\alpha_{10,3}$

I want to get the more digits as possible

Comment: Should that be $z=3^i$?

Comment: No , 3i not 3 to the power i

Comment: Then it's just a geometric series.  $\frac1{3^i10^{3i}}=\frac1{3000^i}$  Looking at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoneham_number) I think you mean the Stoneham number $\alpha_{10,3}$ in which case, you do need $10^{3^i}$

Comment: The result is 3000/2999 , is that right ?

Comment: I make it $\frac1{2999}$.  The sum starts at $i=1$, not $i=0$.  But this is certainly not a Stoneham number.  A rational number is not normal in any base.  Please reread the definition of Stoneham number.

Comment: I mean $\alpha 10,3 $ the stoneham number , how can i calculate its expansion

Comment: First, you need to correct your question.

Comment: It 's done , i hope it 's clear now

Comment: This question is directly related to project Euler [problem 731](https://projecteuler.net/problem=731). This might be indicated somewhere in the question, possibly by mean of the [project-euler] tag.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoneham_number), $\alpha_{10,3}$ is defined as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{3^k}3^k}$$
This converges very rapidly, so getting a lot of digits shouldn't be hard.  The first question to answer is what is the truncation error caused by stopping after say $N$ terms.  The error is $$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac1{10^{3^k}3^k}$$
To estimate this, set $$a_k=\frac1{10^{3^k}3^k}$$
Then $$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{10^{3^k}3^k}{10^{3^{k+1}}3^{k+1}}=\frac13\frac1{100^{2 \cdot 3^k}}<\frac1{300},$$ so that the truncation error is less than $$a_{N+1}(1+\frac1{300}+\frac1{300^2}+\cdots)=\frac{300}{299}a_{N+1}$$
That is, the truncation error is less than $\frac{300}{299}$ times the first omitted term.  The terms decrease so fast that effectively, we don't have to worry about the truncation error.  Choose $N$ so large that $a_{N+1}$ is negligible.

As for actually computing the digits, that depends on what kind of software you have available.  You need some arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic package.  A list can be found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)

Note that $\frac1{a_5}\approx 2.43\cdot10^{245}$ so calculating four terms will give you about $244$ decimal digits.

Comment: I have made an edit to your equation. (You could choose to now tighten the bounds.)